# How to handle Self-Tracking Entities InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, exception, self-tracking-entities

STEs throw two types of Exception:

- UpdateException
- InvalidOperationException

With UpdateException we can check the inner SQLExeption.Number to identify the the Exception (ex. 515=NullNotAllowed)

InvalidOperationException seems not to expose a code. The Hresult property is protected.

Currently I am parsing InvalidOperationException.Message which is ugly:

```
Try
    Using ctx AS New MyEntities
        ctx.Orders.ApplyChanges(order)
        ctx.SaveChanges()
    End Using
Catch ex As InvalidOperationException When ex.Message.Contains("...foreign-key properties is non-nullable")
    Throw New FaultException("...")
Catch ex As UpdateException When CType(ex.InnerException, SqlException).Number = SQLErrorNumbers.NullNotAllowed
    Throw New FaultException("...")
End Try
```

How are we supposed to differentiate InvalidOperationExceptions?
Is there a list of possible InvalidOperationExceptions?
Can one access the protected HResult?

EDIT
No I am not talking about the "duplicate entries" InvalidOperationExceptions!
I am getting an InvalidOperationException "The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable...".

Comment: For a more detailed discussion see [How to handle Self-Tracking Entities InvalidOperationException](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/8ee96457-0182-4e6c-a925-d8c87b13be65)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way around the ugly exception handling with STE.